Is it possible to export a JIRA plan (to .csv) through the Python JIRA API?
I have a JIRA Plan that I want to export to .csv.  If I go into JIRA and select the Plan there is an export option.  That works great.  I cannot seem to find any documentation in the python API that lets me select a plan for export.  Does anyone know if this is possible?
Reviewed docuemntation and could not find any mention of using Plans in the API.
